# How do you consume info from an API which produces data faster than you can consume?

Tags: rest, api

How do you consume info from an API which produces data faster than you can consume ?

Answer (score 0):

You can throttle your API Calls to the Producer using API Rate Limiter. You can only make the number of calls to producer which can be consumed by the consumer per second.